# Oracle Query to be translated to Snowflake

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have been facing an issue while converting a query from Oracle to snowflake. Could you please help out. Sample Oracle query is below.

```
select level,dummy,length(dummy)
from (select 'XYZ' dummy from dual
      union 
      select 'YS' dummy from dual
    ) dual
connect by level < length(dummy)
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Please don’t use images, edit your question to include all information as editable text

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971827/what-is-level-equivalent-in-snowflake

Comment: @MikeWalton Wouldn't help as prior is mandatory in snowflake.